# How to make Tkinter Button image background go away

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a game of chess using Tkinter, I have a button that is a .png of a chess piece, but even after setting the backgroundthickness = 0 and borderwiidth = 0 and releif="sunken" the background won't go away.

The chess piece is a transparent png (I think) but it seems the issue is with the button not showing the image's transparency, so the border of the image is still there.
How do I make it so that the button is only the chess piece without the white background?

Here is the code:

```
    def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file="pawn.png")
    self.pawn = tk.Button(self.master, image=self.image, relief="sunken", borderwidth=0, highlightbackground="white",
                       highlightthickness=0)
    self.dragging = False
```

[image: Pawn image]

[image: pawn image]

Comment: The transparency of the image *works within the button*, but the button itself does not have transparent background.  You can verify it by setting the background color of the button to different colors.

Comment: Instead of creating a button, have you tried directly adding the image to the canvas?